# intersection standard

Tags: linear-algebra

Could you please help me to solve this problem and help me to understand how to get the solution:

I should find the intersection for these two lines:

$$\begin{align}L_1: \frac{x+1}{-2} = \frac{y+1}{2} = \frac{z-6}{4} \\L_2: \frac x 1 = \frac{y+5}{2} = \frac{z+1}{3}\end{align}$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Each equality is an equation. You have a system of 4 equations with 3 unknowns to solve. Start by writing down this system.

Comment: $x=1$, $y=-3$, and $z=2$ is the answer I believe.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: I helped you with the MathJax typesetting syntax this time since you are new, but you are expected to learn it for your future questions and answers as it is standard on this site. You can click "edit" button to see how I wrote it.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look on the instructions and follow the guidelines in the future.

Answer (score 0):

from your first equation we get$$x=-2t-1,y=2t-1,z=4t+6$$with a real number $t$ and the secon
$$x=s,y=2s-5,z=3s-1$$
can you solve this system?
from this system we get
$$s=-2t-1$$
$$2s-5=2t-1$$
$$3s-1=4t+6$$
from the first equation we obtain
$$2(-2t-1)-5=2t-1$$ thus $t=-1$ and $s=1$ and the last equation if fulfilled.
setting $$\frac{x+1}{-1}=\frac{y+1}{2}=\frac{z-6}{4}=t$$ and so on

Comment: Thank you! I am still quite puzzled. I don't quite get where does the s and t come from...

Comment: @MiMaKo $t$ just stands in for the first equation. If you take $-(x+1)/2=t$ then $x=-2t-1$. Same for for $y$ and $z$ and for the second equation.

Comment: @MiMaKo In other words, he just defined $s$ and $t$ by taking $$\frac{x+1}{-2}=\frac{y+1}{2}=\frac{z-6}{4}=t$$ $$\frac{x}{1}=\frac{y+5}{2}=\frac{z+1}{3}=s$$

Comment: Okay, I see. And what do you get for the solution?

Comment: we get $$x=1,y=-3,z=2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question: How do you obtain the first equation: 2(−2t−1)−5=2t−1? I mean where does this equation come from?


Sorry, it's been ages when I studied maths.

Comment: we have $$2s-5=2t-1$$ and $$s=2t-1$$ then we have $$2(-2t-1)-5=2t-1$$

Comment: Oh yeah, now it's clear. Thank you so much!